# How to verify realtime update for facebook page connected with App?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

How to verify that the facebook page connected with facebook App ?

I tried to subscribe realtime update for page.

Added an App to Get Realtime Updates:

```
 I Make a POST call to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/<page id>/tabs with app_id 
 set to my app's ID and page accesstoken as param - receive true from api
```

Is there any API to confirm page is now connect with app, which I mentioned app_id in the above URL?

```
 I tried GET Call to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/<page id>/tabs, 
  there is no information about app_id.
```

Any suggestion,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/tabs/#publish

It states:

> If the app is not configured as a Page tab app in the App Dashboard it
>   will only be installed for the Page and not added as a tab. This is
>   useful if you are subscribing to real-time updates from the Page.

So, if your app is not configured are Page Tab App, you'll not be able to see it via the `/{page_id}/tabs` endpoint from my understanding.

Comment: Yeah, I read the doc link and I got successful response "true". But unable to verify the settings about app_id.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Have you understood what I wrote? Especially the last sentence?

Comment: Can you point me where to configure Page Tab App in App dashboard ?

Comment: `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{app_id}/settings/` and then "Add platform"

Comment: I got the page tab settings, I am not sure about what detail to give in this dashboard. I already called POST API.